# How to generate 12 digits Unique ID in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to set the ID in the **Sequelize Postgres** model. I am using it in the **Node**. For each entry, it should set unique i.e previously not set ID `(eg. 787987979011)`. For the first entry, it should be 000000000000 and increment for upcoming entries respectively. I saw Sequelize documentation I didn't found anything. There they have provided the UUID4 option, but I can't use that for me.

Comment: does it need to be that many digits?  can you just do an auto incrementing id?  1, 2, 3, 4, etc

Comment: That doesn't really seems to be a great design decision, you could achieve the same with a simple primary auto increment column.

Comment: @dmikester1 yes we need many digits

Comment: @briosheje We need in this format, these are also to be used for the folder structure.

Comment: @RuturajMore you can transform the value through a getter, what is the reason for saving it in this format? You could use a numeric value and apply a left padding so that if for reasons unknown in two years you will need the values padded by two more zeros you won't have to deal with extra issues.

Comment: @briosheje You might be right, but we need it in the mentioned format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function, var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*9000000000) + 1000000000;